# Ignore specific character in Npp regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm working with the Notepad++ flavour of regex. This...

```
Find: ([^`]{1,23} )
Replace: $0\n
```

...takes this input string...

> Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party.

...and produces this output string:

> Now is the time for all
>
> good men to come to the
>
> aid of the party.

It splits the string into lines of 24 or fewer non-backtick (`) chars, splitting after spaces. It only works if the final character of the input string is also a space character.

This string...

> Now is the time for all good men to █come to the aid█ of the party.

...splits differently.

> Now is the time for all
>
> good men to █come to
>
> the aid█ of the party.

I'm looking for a way to skip over the █ characters - to process the input string as if the █s were not there.

*[Notes: ` (backtick) characters are reserved to enclose text formatting tags, to be inserted later. █ characters will be used to mean "this bit of text will have tags inserted later", so they **will** be clensed, but not yet. I'm using █ (full block) to represent the Unicode 7F (del) character here, because 7F doesn't display properly. I can also use Perl flavour regex in AHK, if absolutely necessary.]*

These regex patterns finds fail to ignore █:

```
(([^`]|█?){1,23} )
((([^`])|(█)?){1,23} )
((([^`])|(?:█)){1,23} )
```

So, is there a way to do this?

Comment: In my editor this is working  properly.   `(?:[^\s]\s*){18}`  replace with  `$0\n`

Comment: @Haji Rahmatullah This works but ignores paragraph boundaries. Usually we'll want to format words **within** each paragraph and "reset" at the start of the next paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
(?:[^`█]█*){1,23}[ ]
```

This matches any character except for a backtick or a [full block](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm) followed by zero or more full block characters and allows the whole thing to be repeated between 1 and 23 times. This ensures that the full block characters are not counted toward the `{1,23}` quantifier.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HJFKos/1)**.

You may also use Unicode codepoints (which looks better, in my opinion):

```
(?:[^`\x{2588}]\x{2588}*){1,23}[ ]
```

Moreover, if the final character (of the last match) doesn't have to be a space character, you may use:

```
(?:[^`\x{2588}]\x{2588}*){1,23}(?: |$)
```